# Mono Android. Unit test framework

Tags: android, unit-testing, mono, xamarin.android

Are there some unit test frameworks which supports mono android applications?
I already tried default Visual Studio test framework and NUnit framework without any luck.
My last try: I created Mono Android class library, referenced nunit.framework, wrote tests. But when I tried to launch them I've got exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0'
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

I'm sure that it's because of incompatibility of mono android assemblies with other assemblies...
So my question: How to put it to work? Or maybe there are some other unit tests frameworks for mono android applications?

**UPD:** Workaround for this issue.
Since I needed to test the platform independent models only I just created separate "proxy" Windows Class Library project and added to it links to model classes from my Mono for Android Class Library (Project => Add existing Item... => [select all files which should be added as links] => Add As Link).
So I received compatible with any Unit test framework assembly which consists of classes which should be tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're look for running your Visual Studio Unit Tests under Mono for Android, I've written a compatibility layer for that together with a GUI.

Check it out [here](https://bitbucket.org/mayastudios/monodroid-unittest/overview)

[image: Tests Overview]
[image: Tests Details]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to run your unit tests on devices (or inside the emulator) then you should have a look at [Andr.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Andr.Unit) Mono for Android test **runner** for [NUnitLite](http://nunitlite.org/) (0.6). It's similar (same UI and NUnitLite version) to [Touch.Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065071/net-unit-test-runner-for-ios/7591888#7591888) (iOS) even if it (currently) is a bit behind in terms of features (no network logging).

**Disclaimer:** I wrote the runner

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference assemblies from a Mono for Android or MonoTouch or Silverlight application, you must use assemblies that have also been compiled against the same profile.

This is the 2.0.5.0 profile.

Comment: yep. It's the reason why we can't use standard .NET assemblies in Silverlight, etc. I know that it's impossible to use nunit and mono.android together because of different versions of referenced assemblies. So my question: maybe someone faced with same problems and resolved it. Currently I'm trying to recompile nunit using mscorlib v 2.0.5.0 maybe that will solve a problem. It that fail I'll play with mono at mac.

Comment: @NicoGranelli: I solved this problem successfully. I'll update my post with accepted solution soon.  
@jpobst: btw, thanks for a really great mono android examples at github.

Comment: @NicoGranelli I've updated my post with workaround.

Comment: @Igor: Interesting, but couldn't find your post via Google. Can you post the link? Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas Weller, look at question in this post. Workaround was described after **UPD**